# How to update text in a UITextField programmatically in a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to dynamically update the text in a UITextField while in a loop and the text does not show up in real time.  When the loop is complete it will display the final value.  How do I get the text to display each time it is updated in the loop?  I have found many threads on updating in a tableview but this text field is just on the main app.
Here is a simple app with a text field and a button.

in ViewController.h
    #import

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
- (IBAction)pressMe:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

in ViewController.m
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myButton,myText;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myText.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)pressMe:(UIButton *)sender {

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        NSString *m = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        NSLog(@"%@",m);
        [myText setText:m];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.05];
    }
}
@end
```

The texfield delegate is connected to the view controller.  This is a simple app to illustrate what I am trying to do.  My actual app is trying to display lat lon from the gps to the screen with continual updates.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically what happens is that you are running the loop in the main thread, the same one that is responsible for updating the UI. So because the thread is busy running your loop, it can't update the UI. Once your pressMe: message finishes, the UI will be updated. If you want to update the UI at every step of your loop, it needs to run on a separate thread and call a UI reload to the main thread.

Comment: Answer edited with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to update the text in the fields with GPS coordinates, I'd suggest setting the text in `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` (assuming you are using `CLLocationManager` to track user location). This method is called as and when location is updated. No need for GCD here.

Sample Code:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *mostRecentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    latitudeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", mostRecentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    longitudeTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", mostRecentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{      });` for UI updates in different thread. [textfield setNeedsDisplay] also can work if you are already in main thread

Answer (score 0):

Try This Once..

```
-(IBAction)btnPress:(id)sender
{

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        NSString *m = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        NSLog(@"%@",m);

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(call:) toTarget:self withObject:m];
        sleep(1);
    }
}

-(void)call:(NSString *)str
{
    _myText.text = str;
}
```

Comment: Button press is called on main thread and you are updating UI on secondary thread. Instead on button press you should run loop on background thread and sleep, and update UI on main thread.

Comment: Why this comment is down voted? Can have explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSTimer *timer;
    NSInteger i;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   i=0;       

   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
       target:self
       selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
       userInfo:nil
       repeats:YES];    


   myText.delegate = self;
 }

 - (IBAction)StopUpdate:(UIButton *)sender {
    [timerinvalidate]
 }
 -(void)targetMethod{
    NSString *m = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    i++;
    [myText setText:m];
 }
```

Comment: Plz. create a button and set they action "StopUpdate". this method used for stop updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
dispatch_queue_t Queue = dispatch_queue_create("",0);
    dispatch_async(Queue, ^{
        for (int i=1 ; i<=10;i++) {
            sleep(1);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                myTxtFld.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            }
            );
        }
    });
}
```